# Java negative BigInteger toString

Tags: java, tostring, biginteger

It seems I have a two's complement issue with Java's BigInteger. 
I have a 64-bit integer where only the msb and the second msb are set to 1, the rest is 0.

In decimal this comes up to: -4611686018427387904

The Java side of my application receives this decimal number as a string, and converts it to BigInteger like so:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("-4611686018427387904", 10);
```

Then, it needs to display this number both in binary and hex forms.
I tried to use:

```
String bin = bi.toString(2);
String hex = bi.toString(16);
```

but I'm getting:

```
-100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

-4000000000000000
```

whereas I expect to get:

```
1100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

c000000000000000
```

Any tips?

Comment: If you have a 64 bit signed integer, why are you using `BigInteger` rather than `long`?

Comment: it can be bigger than 64

Comment: So you want the 2s-complement version, but without a fixed size? It's not clear to me how you'd represent that. What would you expect to see for "-1" for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `BigInteger.toByteArray()` method, that returns two's complement representation of `BigInteger` as a `byte[]`. All you need is to print that array in hex or binary form:

```
byte[] bs = bi.toByteArray();
for (byte b: bs) {
     System.out.print(String.format("%02X", 0xff & b));
}
```

Comment: this works great, but I can't get it to work in binary (never been good with string formatting...)

Answer (score 3):

#### Number always fits in 64 bits:

If your number always fits in 64 bits you can put it in a long and then print the bits / hex digits.

```
long l = bi.longValue();
String bin = Long.toBinaryString(l);
String hex = Long.toHexString(l);

System.out.println(bin);
System.out.println(hex);
```

#### Number may not always fit in 64 bits:

If the number *does not* always fit in 64 bits, you'll have to solve it "manually". To convert a number to it's two's complement representation you do the following:

- If number is positive, do nothing
- If number is negative:

  - Convert it to its absolute value
  - Complement the bits
  - Add 1

For a `BigInteger` the conversion looks as follows:

```
if (bi.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0)
    bi = bi.abs().not().add(BigInteger.ONE);
```

If you print it using `bi.toString(2)` you'll still get the sign character, instead of a leading `1`. This can be solved by simply appending `.replace('-', '1')` to the string.

Comment: so to get the hex representation I would need to remove the minus sign and adjust the first hex character?

Answer (score 1):

The binary number 1100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 is definitely a positive number, right. It's equal to 2^63 + 2^62.
I don't see why you'd expect a negative number to become positive when you convert to base 2 or base 16.

You are confusing the base n representation with the internal representation of numbers.

Comment: "where - sign is the first bit" is a bit of a simplification of [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Answer (score 1):

If the number is 64 bits or less, then the simple way to solve this is to convert to a `long` and then use `Long.toHexString()`.

Answer (score 0):

what you mean?
Do you want to get Two's complement？

if you mean that, maybe i can give you an example

```
import java.util.*;
public class TestBina{
static void printBinaryInt(int i){
System.out.println("int:"+i+",binary:");
System.out.print("  ");
for(int j=31;j>=0;j--)
   if(((1<<j)&i)!=0)
    System.out.print("1");
   else
    System.out.print("0");
  System.out.println();
 }
 public static void main(String [] args){
  Random rand = new Random();
  int i = rand.nextInt();
  int j = rand.nextInt();
  printBinaryInt(i);
  printBinaryInt(j);
  printBinaryInt(10);
  printBinaryInt(-10);
 }
}
```